# How can I sum numbers from user input inside of a for loop?

Tags: python

I am being asked by an exercise assigned to me to ask for a price (through the input function) and repeat this input 7 times. Then, I am required to sum up the numbers from the user input and I am a little confused as of the direction I should be heading.

```
    for in range(7):
        input("What is the price? "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0
for i in range(7):
    total += int(input("What is the price? "))
```

Comment: @ChristopherFernandes If the answerer's post solved your question, please accept and/or upvote the answer per stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#create empty list called numbers

numbers = []

#create for loop to take user input and append to list

for i in range(7):
    numbers.append(input('What is the Price?'))

#then convert the list into integer type and call the sum function on it

sum(int(i) for i in numbers)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track. Store the total in a variable you define, and start with it at 0. It would look something like this:

```
    total = 0
    for i in range(7):
        total += float(input("What is the price? "))
```

Each time we get input, the value of it is added to total. Note that you could use int instead of float if you know the numbers are integers.

Comment: Your indentation is a little off, just saying.